# Try to send a put Request via Postman to my Webservice but get an notNull Violation: Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Ok, I have a express webservice and try to make a put request where i send some userdata. When i send the request via Postman i get an notNull Violation Error. I have set in the User model the param of allowNull to false

I have tried a lot but i cant fix the problem

Ok First the User Route

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let id = parseInt(req.params.id);
      let user = await models.User.findById(id);

      if (user) {
        await user.update({
          firstname: req.body.firstname,
          lastname: req.body.lastname,
          email: req.body.email,
          username: req.body.username
        });
        res.json({ id: id, message: "updated" });
      } else {
        next({ id: id, message: "user not found", status: 404 });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });
```

I send a put request via postman where is send all data in the body but i get an ERROR:

```
"message": "notNull Violation: User.firstname cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: User.lastname cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: User.email cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: User.username cannot be null"
}
```

But i send in the body the whole data.

Comment: You have setup the body-parse package into your server express?

Comment: Yes  i have set the body-parser package

Comment: You should consider add a validator for your inputs before the handler request. Something like ‘route.put(“/:id”, handlerValidator, handlerRequest)’ then in that validator Can you check the presence of each body.parameter that you need